# Route returning 404 error not found, how can I fix this

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been trying to access "localhost/CompanyRegistration/Index", 404
error has been returned so far.. guys what am I doing wrongly???

Here is my RouteConfig.cs

```
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Routing;
 namespace Supply_Manager
 {
   public class RouteConfig
   {
      public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
      {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           "Default",
           "{controller}/{action}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           "CompanyRegistration",
           "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "CompanyRegistration", action = "Index"}
        );  
      }
   }
 }
```

Here is WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace Supply_Manager
{
   public static class WebApiConfig
   {
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
      }
   }
}
```

Here is Global.asax.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;
namespace Supply_Manager
{
  public class Global : HttpApplication
  {
      protected void Application_Start()
      {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
      }
  }
}
```

Here is CompanyRegistrationController

```
 using System;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace Supply_Manager.Controllers
 {
    [AllowCrossSiteOrigins]
    public class CompanyRegistrationController : Controller
    {
      [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("url working ....")
    }
  }
}
```

All my Controllers are in a Controller folder
the ConmpanyRegistration Controller file is named "CompanyRegistrationController.cs", still yet its not working, how do I get this resolved

Comment: Index is set as [HttpPost], are you posting the request? Try setting it to [HttpGet]

Comment: am sending a post request, not a get,

Comment: Different Controllers are handling different route, it doesn't matter if an Action is name Index in other Controllers